Users has 2 accounts with same email and provider
One of my users seems to have 2 user accounts with the same email and provider. Is this possible?
I've tried disabling the other account. I want to let them access their old account. I thought you could only have one email address per provider.
Here is an image of the dashboard below. The issue was brought to my attention when the logged in and couldn't see any of their data


You should take this up with Firebase support directly. It's possible there is an issue with the service that they need to know about. Stack Overflow isn't very good at questions asking "is it possible" where the source code isn't available and no documentation discusses the issue.

Thanks Doug, I have submitted it to Firebase Support.

We are having the same exact problem, it seems to be a Firebase Authentication bug, it started a couple of months ago...
